# C++ return structure from method

Tags: c++, return, structure

I would like to return a structure from a method but the returned structure needs to be used in a different class. That is my current code:

Song.h:

```
class song{   
  public:
    Song(char szTitle[50]);
    Song();
    struct ToneStruct;
    ToneStruct GetNextNote();
    ~Song();
};
```

Song.cpp:

```
struct ToneStruct {
    char cTone;
    int iTime;
    int iTimePassed;
};

ToneStruct Song::GetNextNote(){
while (iTempTime != endOfFile) {
//do stuff
    while (iTempTime != 59) {
        //do stuff
    }
    ToneStruct toneStruct(cTone,iPlayTime, iTimePassed);
    return toneStruct;
}
ToneStruct endStruct('X', 0, 0);
return endStruct;
}
```

Because of the method I get an error saying "declaration is incompatible with song.h" and on the structs inside the method it says "incomplete type is not allowed". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this your real code? `Song` is different from `song`. Also please copy and paste error messages **verbatim**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forward declared `struct ToneStruct` *inside* the `song` class, which means it is inside the `song` namespace and is thus accessible as `song::TongStruct`, but you declared a `ToneStruct` structure in the source file *outside* the `song` namespace, which will then be assessible as `ToneStruct`. The compiler will see them as different types.

To fix the error, you should either move the forward declaration out of the class or use the `Song::ToneStruct` for your type.

Comment: Prefer "scope" to "namespace", as namespaces are another thing altogether (that do define a scope as well!)

Comment: @Quentin "For purposes of name lookup, the scope of a class is a namespace" (Bjarne)

Answer (score 0):

`struct ToneStruct` you declare *inside* your `class Song` (or is it `song`?) is different from `struct ToneStruct` you declare at the file level. The formeris a *member type* `Song::ToneStruct`, the latter is a name in the global namespace.

If you want to forward-declare `ToneStruct`, you need to do that outside of any class.

Another option is to define and use `Song::ToneStruct` rather than `::ToneStruct` throughout.

It probably won't help you much because a forward declaration is not enough in this case. Return type of a  function should be a complete type before the function is used. This practically means song.h needs to have `struct ToneStruct` fully defined before you can declare `GetNextNote`.

If you only want to use `GetNextNote` inside `Song.cpp` you might get away with a forward declaration, but then `GetNextNote` probably shouldn't be a public member.